# MSFT botbuilder3.9 issue

Tags: node.js, botframework

We are using MSFT botbuilder 3.9 and have migrated all the code for nodejs to 3.9. but when we try to invoke the bot we get this error: [`Error: Dialog[*:/] not found`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjB5r.png). Please help in solving the issue.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(model);
bot.recognizer(recognizer);


bot.dialog('Greetings', [
    function (session) {
        //session.send('Welcome to the Hotels finder! We are analyzing your message: \'%s\'', session.message.text);
        session.send("Thank you for calling IT Helpdesk. How may i help you? ");
        console.log("Hi..********");
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Greetings'
}).beginDialogAction('HiMadamAction', 'HiMadamDialog', { matches: "HiMadam"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bot does not have a root dialog. You need to add one.

For example:

```
bot.dialog('/', function(session) {
  session.send("Hello world!");
}
```

For more information on Dialogs, check out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-overview